# PixiJS for Haxe won't import - Type Not Found error in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, haxe, pixi.js

I'm trying to run the most basic [PixiJS for Haxe](https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-haxe) sample program, but IntelliJ gives a Type Not Found error.

The failing code:

```
package ;
import pixi.core.Application;
```

The error message:

```
Main.hx:3: characters 7-28 : Type not found : pixi.core.Application
```

I think the issue is PixiJS-specific, as when I follow the same install-and-import steps for other Haxe modules (eg flambe, flixel) they behave as expected. I've tried with both 4.7.1 and 4.5.5, and as both global and project-specific libraries (separately).

[image]
(I hybridized several screenshots to save space)

When running from the console, using:

```
> haxe -main Main -lib pixijs -js output.js
```

Everything seems to compile (running the compiled code results in a `PIXI is not defined` error which is a seperate issue).

UPDATE 1, how I'm adding the dependency:

After executing `haxelib install pixijs`, I follow these steps:

[image]

UDPATE 2, the config being run:

[image]

Comment: Could you add detail on how you've added pixijs to the project?

Comment: @ChristopherMandlbaur I've added those details, the only step I haven't shown is ticking the dependency checkbox once it's been added.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get it working in the dependencies section you could try adding the haxelibs pixijs externs src/ folder as an additional sources root in Project Structure -> Modules -> (module name) -> Sources. That's how it worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't this workaround mean that you either have to duplicate the PixiJS source in your project folder, or move your project root into the Haxe directory? Regardless, I'll still try ^_^

Comment: Duplicating PixiJS in a project-level libs folder, and adding that as an extra source, appears to have just delayed the problem. Now I'm getting `Type not found: Perf` inside of `pixi.plugins.app.Application`

Comment: You don't need to move or duplicate anything. You can add as many source roots as you need and those source roots can be on different drives/locations, For example my screeshot actually has two source roots. I put a white box over the second root since it had the client name inside.

Comment: On your Perf error: Have you tried adding the Perf Externs? https://lib.haxe.org/p/perf.js/

Comment: If you don't need or want to use perf you can also open Application.hx inside your editor and comment out the content of the addStats() function that's at the end of the file. No other references to Perf seem to exist beside that one.

Comment: The externs had already been added, but commenting out that line has worked (sort of). It now appears to compile, but I get a temporary popup error `wrong target JavaScript! You can run only Neko, Flash or JavaScript.`
Let me add the Configuration I'm running to the question, in case it has any baring.